# Accessing objects and tuples from a function

Tags: python, numpy

I have a feeling there should be a very easy way to access specific elements from an evaluated function. A very simple example of what I am trying to achieve is

```
def func(x):
    a = 2*x
    b = x*x
    return 1, 10, 100, (a,b)
```

I define a value for x and the function returns a set of values and a tuple. I would like to retrieve (for example) the first element and the tuple. Code such as

```
hello, cello = func(2)[[0,3]]
```

Returns an error. However I can access these elements individually,

```
bello = func(2)[3]
```

for example.

The function I am using takes a while to evaluate so making it run twice is not a desirable option. Furthermore, if possible I would not like to create a pile of variables for each individual element of the tuple (contains many).

In essence I would like a solution that is along the lines of:

```
hello, cello = func(2)[[0,3]]
```

Where,

```
hello = 1
cello = (4,4)
```

Thanks

Comment: Just unpack and ignore the elements you don't need: `hello, _, _, cello = func(2)`

Comment: I can't really understand what you're asking. This has nothing to do with functions; `[[0,3]]` is simply invalid syntax in Python. If you leave the function out of it and just deal with a tuple of `(1, 10, 100, (2, 3))` it wouldn't work either.

Comment: Numpy arrays allow indexing like `x[[0,3]]`, but not lists or tuples.

Comment: Hi AChampion. While I can do the solution you have suggested, my function actually returns quite a number of variables. (I really should've split them up into more manageable parts). Is there an alternative to typing something like _, _, _, _, _, hello, _, _, _, _, cello, _,_,_,bello = func(2) for example

@DanielRoseman and hpaulj. you are absolutely right, the function returns a tuple. I am trying to access elements and tuples inside a larger tuple by their indexing as my larger tuple can be quite large

Comment: Did you know RHS unpacking can do: `x,_,_,(_,b)=func(3)`?  But my feeling is that a function like this should return a few compound objects (tuple of tuples or dictionaries) rather than a long tuple.  Expecting to ask for the 3rd and 10th items out a long tuple is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can unpack and ignore:

```
hello, _, _, cello = func(2)
```

But if the result is more complicated you can use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
hello, cello, bello = itemgetter(0, 3, 15)(func(2))
```

Or more verbosely:

```
my_results = itemgetter(0, 3, 15)
hello, cello, bello = my_results(func(2))
```

Comment: I didn't know `itemgetter` can take `*args`.  And it can do so with a dictionary as well as lists/tuples.  I wonder it's much faster than a list comprehension.  I learned most of my Python before this was added (and `numpy` doesn't need it).

Comment: I checked `itemgetter`; it's Python code.  `itemgetter([1,2,3])(foo())` is equivalent to `obj=foo(); tuple([obj[i] for i in [1,2,3]])`.  Potentially convenient, but not a speed improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
hello, cello = [func(2)[i] for i in [0,3]]
```

Comment: but this runs `func` for each iteration of `i`.

Comment: `itemgetter` rewrites this so that `func(2)` is evaluated only once.

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution would be to pack the returns into a dictionary and use that to separate the results.

In that way you save yourself the counting of the _ and the code is more readable

return {iteration: iter, Result: res....}

Erg=func(....)

And use

Erg[iteration]

later on.